# django application with postgresql error value too long for type character varying(1)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I have a problem with django app and POSTGRESQL database with the slug field.

Error:

> ```
> value too long for type character varying(1)
> ```

I test my app with sqlite database and everything works fine, but my app does not work in postgresql database. Any ideas why this is the case?

Test 1:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(max_length=254)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug_name = slugify(self.name)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Test 2:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(max_length=500)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug_name = slugify(self.name)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Test 3:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    slug_name = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug_name = slugify(self.name)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert a value with more that one character into a field specified as `character varying(1)`.  SQLite3 will allow this (see https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) but PostgreSQL will give an error - i.e., it enforces that you have specified the maximum length as 1.

Comment: why ? i don't define character varying(1)  in this fields and i check that and in postgresql database is not character varying(1),why i take this error?

Comment: Are you sure?  Because that is what the error is telling you.  Can you post the database schema?

Comment: you are correct i have some field with  character varying(1)  just error massage it was error in fields slug,all ok now thank you